# Jquery.AjaxComplete and not executing specific code if I want

Tags: jquery, json

For example I have general code for catching json, that says - "its error request". This code is in ajaxComplete, how can I stop executing specific code from ajaxComplete point?

```
$.post('url', params, 
    function(json){
        if (json.success == false){
             alert('error')
        }
        if (json.success == true){
             alert('success')
        }
    }, 'json'
);
```

Instead of this code in each ajax request, I want to use something like:

```
$().ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr){
        if (json.success == false){
             stop_execution_of_post()
        }
        if (json.success == true){
             proceed_execution_of_post();
        }
}
```

Than in post, you would only to write this:

```
$.post('url', params, 
    function(json){
        alert('success')
    }, 'json'
);
```

Is that possible to STOP from execution SPECIFIC ajax function?

Comment: Please post an example of your code and a better explanation of what exactly you want to stop from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ajaxComplete` you can override an internal method of jQuery.  Obviously you need to be careful because the internal method may change.  This is written against jQuery 1.4.

The method is jQuery's `httpSuccess(xhr)`.  This takes an `XMLHTTPRequest` object.  When it returns `false` jQuery's AJAX error handler is called (`handleError`).  Most notably the `success` handler is not called.  Note that the `complete` handler is always called.

An example:

```
// Remember the old function
var oldhttpSuccess = jQuery.httpSuccess

// Create the override
jQuery.httpSuccess = function (xhr) {
    // Record the result from the old function
    var success = oldhttpSuccess(xhr)
    // If that's bad return 
    if (!success) {
        return success
    }

    // Do our custom test
    if (weNeedToStop) {
       return false
    }

    // Return the "inherited" success value
    return success
}
```

So whenever our `weNeedToStop` test is true, for any ajax response, the success handler is not called.